# How to return a double with Rpois function

Tags: r, integer, poisson

```
d<-rpois(100, 1.54)
 > print (d)
 [1] 2 2 0 4 2 2 3 1 1 2 0 2 1 3 1 1 0 2 2 1 1 2 2 3 3 1 1 3 0 3 1 0 2
  [34] 2 1 3 2 2 1 2 1 2 0 3 0 2 2 2 0 2 3 2 4 0 1 3 2 0 3 1 1 4 0 0 2 2
 [67] 1 0 1 0 0 4 1 1 0 0 3 0 0 2 3 1 0 1 0 0 0 2 0 2 3 0 2 4 0 1 2 1 0
[100] 2
```

What should I do to make it return like `(3.665446)`?

Comment: Would you like the outcome of a Poisson-variable to be 3.665446? A Poisson-distributed variable can only take discrete values. 3.665446 looks like a realisation of a *continuous* variable and is therefore not possible as an outcome.

Comment: What should be the meaning of that `3.665446` ?

Comment: Sir, your question isn't very clear, what are you trying to compute ? The density, the distribution ? Because [Rpois](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/Poisson.html) is dedicated to generating random deviates of a Poisson law.

Comment: This is pretty close `mean(rpois(10000, 3.66))` :)